# Saving XML File to Database Every Week

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, storage

I am downloading the same XML file every-week when the XML file is updated. However I would like to know how I could store this file weekly in a MySQL database.

A sample RSS feed is: http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/xml

My Database scheme is:

```
link    text    utf8_unicode_ci                                      
name    text    utf8_unicode_ci                                      
type    text    utf8_unicode_ci                              
category    text    utf8_unicode_ci                                      
categorylink    text    utf8_unicode_ci                                      
artistlink  text    utf8_unicode_ci                                      
price   text    utf8_unicode_ci                                      
image55 text    utf8_unicode_ci                                      
image60 text    utf8_unicode_ci                      
image170    text    utf8_unicode_ci
rights  text    utf8_unicode_ci
itemcount   text    utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: @XcodeDev: What have you tried? What problems have you encountered? Do you have any code for us to debug? Have you looked up tutorials on how to import XML into a database?

Comment: @jnpcl I haven't tried anything. I wanted to know how I could do this first before I try anything.

Comment: @XcodeDev: Set up your MySQL database, and post the database schema here. Post a sample of your XML file (replace values if it's sensitive data). Play around with PHP's SimpleXML class. This isn't a "Here's what I want, give me some code." site..

Comment: @jnpcl I wasn't aiming for that. My question is how can I do this, not give me code I noob no speekz anglish.

Comment: @XcodeDev: You've been told how to do this... via a `cron` job. Since you tagged with `php`, we assume you want a PHP script that will parse the XML (via `SimpleXML`) and run `INSERT` statements on your MySQL db. You've given us zero information, and it appears that you've put zero effort into your project.

Comment: I have actually spent weeks on my project. Anyway, I have updated the question and inserted all the information you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a cron job:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Assume that you have access to the cPanel of your web server? There should be an option in there for setting up cron jobs.

Comment: Yes there is an option for doing so.